# Cannot build jhipster project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jhipster

I cannot build a simple project (just created with `yo jhipster`) in Eclipse.
I'm getting the error:

> Maven Dependency Problem
>   Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6

Thare are other errors too but i think this is the one that is causing problems.
I can compile and run the same project from command line with `mvn spring-boot:run`

I googled for the error and found lots of solutions but unfortunately none worked.
If i check Eclipse configuration i can see that `java.home` points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7` no matter what i do.
I tried to edit the `eclipse.ini` file adding `-vm C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe`
I also double checked that my workspace and project are using a Jdk and not a Jre Vm.

Can someone please point me to the right direction please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before... you are probably running your Eclipse with a JRE rather than a JDK. The sun tools jar is actually part of the latest JDK, and doesn't necessarily need to be inferred directly in your project.

See my comments, issue #1, in the attached link:
[JHipster Eclipse project running out of memory in "main"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468726/jhipster-eclipse-project-running-out-of-memory-in-main/22469966#22469966)

Answer (score 0):

Try with STS and everything works. Seems to be an issue with your eclispe

Comment: Really? Is this an answer?

Comment: Also, my Eclipse can run quite well Spring projects so i think my setup is correct... Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

I've imported the [sample jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app) in Eclise (without STS) and everything was OK, after installing the maven dependencies.

To run the project, run as an application and search for the Application (com.mycompany.myapp.Application)